# How to replace a service-decorator with a custom decorator in Symfony?

Tags: symfony, symfony4, sylius

In a **Symfony**-4-Application based on **Sylius**, there is a service decorator placed deep in their [Core](https://github.com/Sylius/Sylius/blob/23aeeb5e6b563518192c79a2bc768e254d9ea9ad/src/Sylius/Bundle/CoreBundle/Resources/config/services.xml#L156):

```
   <service id="sylius.order_item_quantity_modifier.limiting" class="Sylius\Component\Core\Cart\Modifier\LimitingOrderItemQuantityModifier" decorates="sylius.order_item_quantity_modifier" decoration-priority="256">
        <argument type="service" id="sylius.order_item_quantity_modifier.limiting.inner" />
        <argument>9999</argument>
    </service>
```

However, I want to replace this decorator as I [don't want this limitation that is hard coded](https://github.com/Sylius/Sylius/issues/10740) in its service definition.

How can I replace this?

I tried to define a service decorator around this service decorator, but it does not apply for some reasons:

```
app.core.cart.modifier:
    class: AppBundle\Component\Core\Cart\Modifier\MyLimitingOrderItemQuantityModifier
    decorates: sylius.order_item_quantity_modifier.limiting
    decoration_priority: 1000
    arguments:
```

I also tried to replace its service-id with my own class, which didn't work either:

```
   sylius.order_item_quantity_modifier.limiting:
        class: AppBundle\Component\Core\Cart\Modifier\MyLimitingOrderItemQuantityModifier
        decorates: sylius.order_item_quantity_modifier.limiting
        decoration_priority: 100
        arguments:
            - "@app.core.cart.modifier.inner"
```

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: you probably want to decorate `sylius.order_item_quantity_modifier` instead, because `sylius.order_item_quantity_modifier.limiting` is the already decorated service, which you decorate ... again.

Comment: thx @jak but then the original decorator still is enabled and modifies the values

Comment: the "name" of your service must be `sylius.order_item_quantity_modifier.limiting` ... in theory. Hope that works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have 2 or 3 options :

1. Let's say you have **your decorator** which decorates the base service, with a higher priority than the **sylius decorator**, what it means is that :

   - if you use the *XXXXXXX.inner* injected service, instead of being the base service it will be the lower priority decorator : the **sylius decorator** in your case
   - you could just decide to **not** use the *XXXXXXX.inner* injected service and completely rewrite the function which is using the hard-coded value. It's not good for maintainability, but the way it's already done isn't either...
2. You could play with a [Compiler Pass](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/compiler_passes.html) to **remove** the decorator definition, or even **replace the hard-coded** argument if you you want to use another value, or maybe a parameter :-)
   More information about that [can be found here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/definitions.html)

I just saw your issue on the sylius/sylius repository, the second solution might be the best (easy to remove when the core will change)!